# rnpm command not found after "sudo npm install rnpm -g"

Tags: facebook, react-native

I am still new to coding and I ran into a weird problem.

I am trying to use the facebook SDK in my react native app and I was following the tutorials for installing rnpm. However, after I installed rnpm package the "rnpm" command is still unusable. Can someone point out what I did wrong? I already installed the package globally.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since last November, rnpm is part of the React Native core, so you don't need to install rnpm anymore. You can run directly 'react-native link' to link the dependencies that you instal using npm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install npm on your macbook

issue

```
sudo port install npm
```

https://medium.com/@samthor/installing-npm-on-mac-os-x-with-macports-27e9f380ffb7#.58c58rzca

Comment: try sudo rnpm, if that doesn't work issue which rnpm, you may have to setup the path to the program